# Does Amazon have a web server named 'AmazonS3'?

Tags: web-server, amazon-s3

Note that I understand what "Amazon S3" is; I'm asking only about the software that handles the HTTP interface.

If I check the HTTP headers for [github.com](https://github.com), for example, one of the response headers is:

```
server: AmazonS3
```

Does Amazon actually have a web server that it calls 'AmazonS3', or are they just modifying headers from Apache/nginx/etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Server http header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server) means nothing. It is an arbitrary product version string, think [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) but for the server. As such, it is untrustworthy.

Even if this was Amazon S3 (its not, that is a dynamic web site) there are [ways to change the Server header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565985/is-it-possible-to-change-amazon-s3-response-header-server).

Regarding something closer to what you describe, [http Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) does not imply a single backend server either, not that Amazon or GitHub would ever have a single server for anything important.

---

In general, I do not consider big name-brand tech companies to be good examples of off the shelf technology. An organization with huge traffic, a large engineering staff, and an engineering blog is more likely to write parts of their stack from scratch.